# Calling a windowsservice ExecuteCommand to excute a OnCustomCommand on itself?

Tags: c#, windows-services, command, execute, self

ServiceController.ExecuteCommand in C# can be used to send custom command to a windows service. Like here - [How to send a custom command to a .NET windows Service from .NET code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695245/how-to-send-a-custom-command-to-a-net-windows-service-from-net-code)

ServiceController myService = new ServiceController("MyService");

myService.ExecuteCommand(200);

I also understand that the command number should be between 128 and 256.

 So I tried doing the same with both the service name and service display name, but crashed the windows service both times. It doesn't get caught in try catch. 
 And EventViewer says - "The MyService service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s)."

So my question is - Is it possible for a windows service to call ExecuteCommand within itself to invoke a call to OnCustomCommand() in the same windowsservice?

Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible for it to be done. I had done it once where a WCF service hosted within a Windows Service, called the host's methods using ExecuteCommand. If you need help with the syntax, I would like to see the code you are working on right now.