# Stop/cancel active file processing in C#

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have an Windows service.It uses Filewatcher API to watch for any new files and start processing the file.

Suppose If i want to stop the file processing during runtime (Note I want to stop the active file processing)how can I do that from any external windows application.

Note: Already I am communicating with the windows service from the external windows application

Answer (score 0):

Communicate to the windows service to stop processing and set `FileSystsemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents` to `false`.  When you want to continue processing, communicate to the service and set it back to `true`.

Without more detail about how you're actually communicating between processes, I can't provide much more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you external application is a .NET windows application, please refer to the following SO Question

- [How to send a custom command to a .Net windows Service from.Net code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3695245/1012641)